# Any required callbacks to WP.com or WP.org?

Tags: javascript

China is blocking both WP.com and WP.org. I would like to know if WP4.0 includes any callbacks or references to files such as javascript libraries located on these domains, because I must plan for mainland Chinese users not being able to access them.

Comment: There are no required callbacks to WP.com or WP.org. These callbacks are for checking updates for WP, plugin and themes. Your website should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little hard to quickly audit WP code base for wordpress.org links, because they are extensively used in inline documentation. On top of my head the main (if not only) requests are probably to `api.wordpress.org` for updates.

For resources WP generally only uses bundled assets. The two notable exceptions are:

1. Deprecated libraries (such as prototype), which aren't used in core anymore. They are registered to load from `ajax.googleapis.com` and no longer bundled.
2. Web fonts in admin which aren't bundled because of technical challenges. They are registered to load from `fonts.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Do you know if there are fallbacks when the x.googleapis.com domain fails to load? It is blocked as well.

Comment: No, there are no fallbacks, since if these were bundled they wouldn't need to be loaded from CDNs in first place. Deprecated libs are unlikely to cause issue, but fonts you will have to deal with.